# jquery isotope blank spaces

Tags: jquery, sorting, spaces

I'm currently experimenting with jquery isotope but having trouble with the way its sorting the items.

I guess it's best to explain by showing you my current script [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KayCharles/D87X8/4/).

When you click on the second box it gets wider and turns green. Thats good, however now there is a big gap in the first row after the first box. What I'd like it to do is to fill that empty space with two of the other smaller boxes (preferable 3 and 4).

Is there some kind of trick to force it to fill all the empty spaces? If anybody could give be nudge into the right direction I'd be much obliged. :-)

```
$(function(){
var $container = $('#container'),
  $items = $('.item');

 $container.isotope({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  layoutMode : 'fitRows',
 masonry: {
    columnWidth: 30
  },
resizesContainer : true,
getSortData : {
  fitOrder : function( $item ) {
      var order,
        index = $item.index();

       if ( $item.hasClass('large') && index % 2 ) {
        order = index + 1.5;
      } else {
        order = index;
      }
      return order;
    }
  },
  sortBy : 'fitOrder'
});


  $items.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // nothing to change if this already has large class
    if ( $this.hasClass('large') ) {
      return;
    }
    var $previousLargeItem = $items.filter('.large');

    $previousLargeItem.removeClass('large');
    $this.addClass('large');
    $container
      // trigger layout and sort
      .isotope();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the wrong layout mode for your purpose. If you use masonryHorizontal and increase the height of the container it looks much better! I also removed getSortData since it doesn't seem do be necessary.

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/D87X8/5/

```
$(function () {
    var $container = $('#container'),
        $items = $('.item');

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        layoutMode: 'masonryHorizontal',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 30
        },
        resizesContainer: true
    });


    $items.click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        // nothing to change if this already has large class
        if ($this.hasClass('large')) {
            return;
        }
        var $previousLargeItem = $items.filter('.large');

        $previousLargeItem.removeClass('large');
        $this.addClass('large');
        $container
        // trigger layout and sort
            .isotope();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Your idea goes into the right direction, however now the large active green box sorts itself after the smaller boxes.

I want the active box to be alone in one row (like when clicking on boxes 1, 2, 3).

Is there a way to force the active class to be sorted first?